# rstudio in linux with Gtk fail?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio, bioconductor

I have tried to open the RStudio in Ubuntu but I faced with below error. it is loading the studio but after opening it is suddenly gone.

```
$ rstudio
Gtk-Message: 11:50:42.854: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 11:50:42.856: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 11:50:42.859: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
load glyph failed err=6 face=0x565548afd120, glyph=2798
load glyph failed err=6 face=0x565548afd120, glyph=2798
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


Ubuntu Version:18.04.2 
R Version: 3.5.2 
Rstudio: 1.1.456
```

Comment: Can you provide what version of Rstudio on what version of Ubuntu did you install ?